# Using a regular expression to replace upper case repeated letters in python with a single lowercase letter

Tags: python, regex, capitalization

I am trying to replace any instances of uppercase letters that repeat themselves twice in a string with a single instance of that letter in a lower case. I am using the following regular expression and it is able to match the repeated upper case letters, but I am unsure as how to make the letter that is being replaced lower case.

```
import re
s = 'start TT end'
re.sub(r'([A-Z]){2}', r"\1", s)
>>> 'start T end'
```

How can I make the "\1" lower case? Should I not be using a regular expression to do this?

Comment: Don't know how to make it lowercase, but your should use `'([A-Z]){2,}'` instead of `'([A-Z]){2}'` to replace any instances.

Comment: Your regex also matches two different caps.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Pass a function](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) as the `repl` argument. The [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects) is passed to this function and `.group(1)` gives the first parenthesized subgroup:

```
import re
s = 'start TT end'
callback = lambda pat: pat.group(1).lower()
re.sub(r'([A-Z]){2}', callback, s)
```

**EDIT**
And yes, you should use `([A-Z])\1` instead of `([A-Z]){2}` in order to *not* match e.g. `AZ`. (See @bobince's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145451/using-a-regular-expression-to-replace-upper-case-repeated-letters-in-python-with/4145495#4145495).)

```
import re
s = 'start TT end'
re.sub(r'([A-Z])\1', lambda pat: pat.group(1).lower(), s) # Inline
```

Gives:

```
'start t end'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't change case in a replacement string. You would need a replacement function:

```
>>> def replacement(match):
...     return match.group(1).lower()
... 
>>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])\1', replacement, 'start TT end')
'start t end'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace(s):
    return " ".join(re.findall(r"[A-Z]){2}", s)).lower()
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regular expression, just pass a function as the replacement like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) say. The problem is your pattern.

As it is, your pattern matches runs of *any* two capital letters. I'll leave the actual pattern to you, but it starts with `AA|BB|CC|`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'repl' parameter that identifies the replacement can be either a string (as you have it here) or a function. This will do what you wish:

```
import re

def toLowercase(matchobj):
   return matchobj.group(1).lower()

s = 'start TT end'
re.sub(r'([A-Z]){2}', toLowercase, s)
>>> 'start t end'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def tol(m):
   return m.group(0)[0].lower()

s = 'start TTT AAA end'
re.sub(r'([A-Z]){2,}', tol, s)
```

Note that this doesn't replace singe upper letters. If you want to do it, use `r'([A-Z]){1,}'`.

Comment: OP says: *repeat themselves twice*

Comment: @SilentGhost. My fault. the re should be as suggested by Ignacio, if single upper characters shouldn't be touched.

Comment: if you look and bobince's and jens's answers you see the shorter way to do this.

Comment: I see, thanks. The question about single upper chars is still open.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING! This post has no re as requested. Continue with your own responsibility!**

I do not know how possible are corner cases but this is how normal Python does my naive coding.

```
import string
s = 'start TT end AAA BBBBBBB'
for c in string.uppercase:
    s = s.replace(c+c,c.lower())
print s
""" Output:
start t end aA bbbB
"""
```