# Regex to replace 4.7uF to 4U7

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with regular expression. Would it be possible to use regex to parse electronic component values from standard form into shorthand:

```
 4.7pF    >  4P7
 16.2kΩ   >  16K2
 22.6nH   >  22N6
```

Ideally the regex would find the letter after the decimal number, and insert it into the place of the decimal point. Also would be good if we could chop off the trailing letter/symbol for the unit.

So far I am matching the decimal number but not sure how to grab the letter *after* the match group, then no idea how to do the replacement.

Cheers

Comment: Regular expressions ('in general') do not support case changes. Use Python for that, as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4145451/2564301

Comment: Are electronic component values already in separated strings or in a larger string (with other things)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, you can use

```
result = re.sub(r'(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))(\w).*', r"\1\3\2", test_str).upper()
```

**[Ideoene Demo](http://ideone.com/1nqwu4)**

Comment: Very quick response and very concise, thank you. Seems to work for arbitrary number of digits before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python complete solution:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\D*(\d+)\.(\d+)(\S).*')
strs = ["4.7pF", "16.2kΩ", "22.6nH"]
result = [p.sub(lambda m: "{0}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1),m.group(3).upper(),m.group(2)), x) for x in strs]
print(result) # => ['4P7', '16K2', '22N6']
```

The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV0bC4/2) is here.

The regex is matching leading non-digits (0 or more), then captures 1+ digits, matches a dot, captures 1 or more digits and then captures 1 non-whitespace character.

In the code, a lambda expression is used inside the `re.sub` method to construct the required replacement string.

Comment: this much of complication was not needed(at least here)

Comment: Let me know what is complex here for you, I will explain

Comment: well not in that way `complex complex`..i was just saying it can be done simply also..though these are relative terms..

Comment: Ok, maybe for the current scenario it might be a bit too much. However, it is a generic approach (if only one capture should be changed and others shouldn't).

Comment: that's why I mentioned `(at least here)` in my comment..i understand yours is generic solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to search:

`([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)(.).*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV0bC4/1))

Then replace it with `\1\3\2`. This will not change the case of the letter representing the unit. Not sure how that can be done.