# How to match complete words for acronym using regex?

Tags: python, regex, alphabet

I want to only get complete words from acronyms with ( ) around them.

For example, there is a sentence
'Lung cancer screening (LCS) reduces NSCLC mortality';
->I want to get 'Lung cancer screening' as a result.

How can I do it with regex?

---

original question:
I want to remove repeated upper alphabets :
"HIV acquired immunodeficiency syndrome are at a particularly high risk of cervical cancer" => " acquired immunodeficiency syndrome are at a particularly high risk of cervical cancer"

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. You can use https://regex101.com to play with regular expressions (set flavor to Python).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'HIV acquired immunodeficiency syndrome are at a particularly high risk of cervical cancer'
print(re.sub(r'([A-Z])', lambda pat:'', s).strip()) # Inline
```

[according to @jensgram answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145451/using-a-regular-expression-to-replace-upper-case-repeated-letters-in-python-with)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to target 2 or more capital letters, I would use `re.sub` here:

```py
inp = "Lung cancer screening (LCS) reduces NSCLC mortality"
output = re.sub(r'\s*(?:\([A-Z]+\)|[A-Z]{2,})\s*', ' ', inp).strip()
print(output)  # Lung cancer screening reduces mortality
```

Comment: Actually, I changed my question because that was the actual question I wanted to ask. Can you also answer that question, please?

Comment: Answer updated, please avoid changing your question after others have already answered.